# Get sound power from waveform

Tags: java, android, audio, fft, waveform

I use ringdroid application (http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/) for get waveform, but if I need get sound power (something like equalizer) I must use Fourier Transform or it is posible without FT? Please can you tell me any hint for this? I am trying to find solution in a lot of pages but without good result. 
Thanks for your answer

Comment: I think no, you need to do FT do get spectr and measure power for every frequency. To show something like equalizer

Comment: And if i want get only one bar (all frequency in one bar) still i need do FT to get coeficient? Thanks.

Comment: If you have curve amplitude versus time, so you can take an Integral to measure power of sound.

Comment: Thank you, i thought so, but in some unknown reason did not work to me and result are not correct.

Comment: You really need to clarify this question. "get sound power" says something completely different from "something like equalizer". What is you want to do? Change the sound in some way? provide a moving volume meter? etc.

Comment: Bjorn Roche: I want show something like this: http://macprovid.vo.llnwd.net/o43/hub/media/1110/7779/Fig01-02_Standard_K-System_and_Loudness_Meters.jpg
No change sound, only visualize like in image.

Comment: @Jakub: Although I think your statement is clear, for future reference, that is typically called a "level meter", or some some variation of that.  If you take the log (see my answer below) it can be called a "sound level meter", and if you weight it by human-perceived loudness, a "loudness meter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the total power, you don't need to do the FFT.  You can **sum the squared amplitudes** and then divide by the total time.

A few things to keep in mind:  1) Make sure you take the square of the amplituded *before* you do the sum.  2) It matters where 0 is here, and the amplitudes need to be deflections from 0, that is deflections from the reading when there's no sound; so if your values range from, 0 to 1024, the no sound value might be 512, and this would need to be subtracted from every value *before* you take the square.

Also, btw, if you're making a level meter for an auditory signal, you might want to take the `log` of the power, since perceived loudness varies as the log, and not the total power.  But this is a perceptual issue to it depend what you want to represent.

Finally, it's worth noting that the power calculated this way (ie, directly from the waveform) will give exactly the same result as if one had calculated the power using the FFT.  This is known as [Parseval's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem).

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the 'R' in 'RMS' here?

Comment: @Marko: Power will go as the square, and it would be incorrect to take the square root.  (RMS power is a misnomer derived from the fact that the average power can be calculated by Vrms*Irms, but the resulting power isn't really Prms, and if calculated directly from the waveform, one shouldn't take the root.)

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very usefull for me. Now i am sure, it is error in ringdroid aplication, because waveform is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Jakub: I'm glad it was helpful.  Before concluding that your data is wrong, I recommend plotting it and taking a look.  It's very easy to get these calculations wrong in some minor detail, which makes the final result look completely wrong, so it's recommended not to assess the data through a single calculation without looking at intermediate results, and a plot is the best quick check.

Comment: Yes I plot the data, and in some songs, curve is absolutely wrong. In my optinion this is unknow bug in ringdroid aplication. Or maybe mp3s is in some case damages, but in audacity aplication is plot correct.